# Power ball em Ruby

Tags: ruby

Fiz o seguinte programa:

```
class PowerBall

  def jogo

    brancas = Array.new
    50.times{brancas << false}

    brancasSorteadas = Array.new
    5.times{brancasSorteadas << 0}

    for x in brancasSorteadas
      j = rand(48) + 1
      if brancas[j-1] == false
        brancas[j-1] = true
        brancasSorteadas[x] = j
      else
        x -= 1
      end
    end

    for x in brancasSorteadas 
      puts "A bola branca eh: #{brancasSorteadas[x]}"
    end

    puts "A bola vermelha eh: #{rand(42)}"
  end
end

a = PowerBall.new
a.jogo
```

O objetivo dele é retirar cinco bolas brancas de um balde de 49 bolas sem repetição e tirar uma bola vermelha de um balde de 42 bolas podendo repetir alguma tirada do balde branco.

Só que o resultado está dando o seguinte:

```
A bola branca eh: 
A bola branca eh:38
A bola branca eh:38
A bola branca eh:38
A bola branca eh:38
A bola vermelha eh:numero aleatorio
```

Variando o numero que se repete a cada vez que o programa é chamado.
Alguém sabe onde está o erro?

Comment: `x` é sempre `0`. Ele não é o índice da array no loop, é cada valor (e a sua array só contém zeros). Acho que além disso tem erros de lógica, mas comece daí.

Answer (score 2):

Você provavelmente veio do universo do javascript em que loops do tipo `for x in array` iteram x variando entre os indices da array. Aqui no ruby a estrutura é:

```
for <variável> in <algo enumerável>
```

E a variável será os **elementos** desse objeto da enumerável, no seu caso a array. Se quer fazer um loop usando os indices pode fazer assim:

```
for x in 0...array.size
```

ou ainda:

```
0.upto(array.size) do |x|
```

ou ainda:

```
array.size.times do |x|
```

Em segundo lugar, você executou `x -= 1` dentro do loop. Isso não existe, você não pode alterar a variável do loop já que ela vai receber o próximo valor da sequencia independente de o que você faça com ela.

Seu loop pode ser então escrito assim:

```
for x in 0...brancasSorteadas.size
  j = rand(48) + 1
  if brancas[j-1] == false
    brancas[j-1] = true
    brancasSorteadas[x] = j
  else
    redo    # reinicia esta iteração do loop sem mudar o x
  end
end
```

Ou ainda:

```
brancasSorteadas.map do
  j = rand(48) + 1
  if brancas[j-1] == false
    brancas[j-1] = true
    next j
  else
    redo
  end
end
```

Ou de forma **muito** mais simples:

```
# Cria uma array com os números de 1 a 48, então escolhe 5 aleatóriamente
brancasSorteadas = (1..48).to_a.sample(5)
```